# Does Mathematica reuse previous computations?

Tags: numerics, convolution, caching

I am doing an analysis of experimental results in which I need to repeat the same `GaussianFilter` hundred of times on different data. As explained in the documentation, `GaussianFilter` just convolves the data with a Gaussian kernel. Does it recompute the kernel every time I call the function, or will it somehow preserve and reuse the previous kernel? Would it be more efficient computationally for me to precompute the kernel (which I could do easily by applying `GaussianFilter` to a `KroneckerDelta` array), then do hundreds of `ListConvolve`s instead of hundreds of `GaussianFilter`s?

Comment: My first guess is that `GaussianFilter` employs FFT (FFT, multiply, inverse FFT). In this case, it would be a very bad idea to replace it by a convolution unless the convolution is also implemented by FFT: The naive way of convolution would require $O(n^2)$ flops for a vector of length $n$ while the FFT method would need only $O(n \, \log(n))$ flops.

Comment: The only way to get a definitive answer about whether your proposed approach would be faster is to try it, *however*, I highly doubt that it would.

Comment: Best way would be to just try it and compare the `RepeatedTimings`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm pretty sure ListConvolve also uses FFT (based on its performance).

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah, that came also to my mind... finally.

Comment: ListConvolve does indeed use FFT.

Comment: [Indeed it does.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#15670)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here I implemented three different versions of Gaussian filtering (for periodic data). It took me a while to adjust the constants and still some of them might be wrong.

Prepare the Gaussian kernel

```
n = 200000;
σ = .1;
t = Subdivide[-1. Pi, 1. Pi, n - 1];
ker = 1/Sqrt[2 Pi]/ σ Exp[-(t/σ)^2/2];
ker = Join[ker[[Quotient[n,2] + 1 ;;]], ker[[;; Quotient[n,2]]]];
```

Generate noisy function

```
u = Sin[t] + Cos[2 t] + 1.5 Cos[3 t] + .5 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[t]];
```

The three methods  with their timings. As Niki Estner pointed out, `GaussianFilter` with the option `Method -> "Gaussian"` performs much batter than `GaussianFilter` with the default emthod.

```
kerhat = 2 Pi/Sqrt[N@n] Fourier[ker];
vConvolve = (2. Pi/n) ListConvolve[ker, u, {-1, -1}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
vFFT = Re[Fourier[InverseFourier[u] kerhat]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
vFilter = GaussianFilter[u, 1./(Pi) σ n, Padding -> "Periodic"]; // RepeatedTiming // First
vGaussian = GaussianFilter[u, 1./(Pi) σ n, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0038
>
> 0.0058
>
> 0.055
>
> 0.0072

```
ListLinePlot[{u, vFFT, vFilter, vConvolve}]
```

[image]

From further experiments with different values for `n`, `GaussianFilter` seems to be slower by a factor 10-20 over a wide range of `n` (from `n = 1000` to `n = 1000000`). So it seems that it does use some FFT-based method (because it has the same speed asymptotics) but maybe some crucial part of the algorithm is not compiled (the factor 10 is somewhat an indicator for that) or does not use the fastest FFT implementation possible. A bit weird.

So, to my own surprise, your idea of computing the kernel once does help but for quite unexpected reasons.

Comment: IIRC, it's using a [discrete Gaussian kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation#The_discrete_Gaussian_kernel), which involves non-compilable modified Bessel functions, so that might be the reason for the added computational effort you observe.

Comment: Yes, that is one reason I proposed using GaussianFilter itself to generate the kernel.

Comment: If I add `Method -> "Gaussian"` to the `GaussianFilter` call, it's about as fast as the other two

Comment: @NikiEstner Ah, that's good to know! Somewhat unexpected that we have to call out _twice_ for a `"Gaussian"` in order to get one, isn't it?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Your results are about 6 times faster than mine.  My platform is Xeon E3-1270, V3, 3.695 MHz; 4 cores, 8 threads; 32 GB ECC memory; Windows 8.1 Prof, 64-bit.  I'm not used to such shenanigans.  Can you suggest a reason?  In any case, thanks for the good work.

Comment: @CElliott I checked the timings once more on my machine and they appear to be correct. I ran the test on a i7 4980HQ which should be a bit faster but not _that_ much faster than your Xeon E3-1270, V3. So I have no clue why this does not run as fast on your machine. The OS that I use is macOS Mojave (10.14.3) and the _Mathematica_ version is 11.3. Maybe your _Mathematica_ version is a bit older and contains less optimized implementations of `ListConvolve` and `GaussianFilter`? I don't know...

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to know for sure, but one way to test for caching is to apply a single command to lots of data sets, or to apply the command separately to each set. For instance:

```
n = 5000;
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 10000}];
GaussianFilter[#, 100] & /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[GaussianFilter[data[[i]], 100], {i, n}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[GaussianFilter[data[[i]], 100 + RandomInteger[{-15, 15}]], {i, n}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The second line generates 5000 different sets of data, each 10000 length. The third applies one Gaussian filter to all the data sets. The third line applies a separate GaussianFilter to each set. The final line forces the GaussianFilter to recompute its kernel. The timings are pretty much the same. This suggests that whatever is happening, the time needed to calculate the Gaussian filter parameters is pretty negligeable.