# Optimize Use of PeakDetect in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, compile, streams, peak-detection

I am quite new to *Mathematica* and I am looking for some advice in order to improve and optimize my code.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Open a stream
2. Read the stream line by line and store it in "data"
3. For each value of "data", I would like to find the position of the first peak and store it in "firstPeaks"
4. Close the stream

How could I optimize this process and make the findAllPeaks function run faster? I tried including the parallelization option but that didn't really change the run time. Running the code as is takes about 15 seconds for a $ 2500 \times 3000 $ array (2500 being the number of data points and 3000 being the number of bytes per data point), which is significantly smaller than what I would like to work with.

I did read the following article: Jon McLoone [10 Tips for Writing Fast *Mathematica* Code](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) and I did try to follow some of the suggestions, namely:

- Using compile.
- Using built-in functions such as `Apply`, `PeakDetect` and `Position`.
- Using parallelization, which didn't seem to help.
- Using `Block`, which also didn't seem to help much in this case.
- And using `"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False` to avoid any symbolic calculations.

```
readlines[n_, m_] := Block[{}, SetStreamPosition[str, index[[n]]]; ReadList[str, {Byte}, m]]

findPeaks = Compile[{{d, _Integer, 1}}, PeakDetect[d, .1, .01], RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]

str = OpenRead[FileNameJoin[{path, fileName}], BinaryFormat -> True];

index = Table[pos = StreamPosition[str]; Skip[str, Byte, lineLength];
   pos, {streamLength}];

Do[data[[i]] = Flatten[readlines[i, lineLength]], {i, 1, streamLength}];

Do[firstPeaks[[i]] = FirstPosition[Apply[findAllPeaks, data[[i]]], 1., {0}], {i, 1, streamLength}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Close[str];
```

Comment: Did you try using `Import` instead of low-level file reading functions? Also, `PeakDetect` is not in the [list of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) which means that putting it inside `Compile` will not do anything (it may even slow things down a little.)

Comment: @etotheix Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange. I notice that your question is well written. However, it would be easier to answer if you could provide also an example file or an example data set. Apart from that, I second C.E.'s suggestions: try to read the data in one chunk as a matrix, e.g. with `Import`. Afterwards `Map` or `ParallelMap` `PeakDetect` over it.

Comment: I suspect that `PeakDetect` uses `GaussianFilter` under the hood; the documentation indicates that. For some reason that is not clear to me, `GaussianFilter` performs poorly without setting the option `Method -> "Gaussian"`. Unfortunately, `PeakDetect` does not feature such an option. In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193335), I showed how `GaussianFilter` can be sped up with `ListConvolve`. One could build a `PeakDetect` from scratch with the information there. It is only a matter of guessing the parameters and the settings for `Padding` etc. correctly.

Comment: I implemented `PeakDetect` from scratch in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186638/731).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Does `SetOptions[GaussianFilter, Method -> "Gaussian"]` have the desired effect on `PeakDetect`?  (`Trace[
 PeakDetect[data],
 _GaussianFilter
 ]` does confirm `GaussianFilter` is called.

Comment: Hm. It setting `SetOptions[GaussianFilter, Method -> "Gaussian"]` does indeed speed up the two-argument variant of `FindPeak`, but there seens to be no difference in timing for the one-argument variant...

Comment: Thank you @C. E., I implemented your PeakDetect and it seem to speed up the computation. What would be the advantage of using Import in this case? The data that I have is a binary file, I tried using Import but it was only able to read the raw data. The Method->"Gaussian" also seems to improve the computation time slightly.

Comment: @etotheix Mathematica is an interpreted language and not very fast. If you leave all the details of how to read the file to Mathematica, by using `Import`, it will use an appropriate, optimized piece of code probably written in C. When you tell it exactly how you want to read the file, Mathematica can't optimize like this.